# Python 3: Spawning Process Subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

We can create non-forked processes with Python 3's `multiprocessing` using a created context:

```
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(42,))
p.start()
```

But suppose I'm working with a subclass of `Process`.  Is there a way to create a `Process` subclass instance using a method other than `fork`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inherit from `ctx.Process`:

```
ctx = multiprocessing.get_context('spawn')
class CustomProcess(ctx.Process):
    # define methods
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.  I'd assumed that the value returned by `multiprocessing.get_context` just contained a reference to `multiprocessing.Process`, but looking deeper into the source I was clearly wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer by @Daniel is perfectly fine (and may be more idiomatic), but note also that you can find the appropriately contextualized subclasses of `Process` deeper in the multiprocessing module (such as `multiprocessing.context.SpawnProcess`).  You can also inherit from these to get the desired behavior.